# Branch.io: Indexing of app dynamic content not having website

Tags: branch.io, firebase-app-indexing

We wanted to index our app contents (dynamic) in search engines and don't have **web application**. I got to know about branch [Firebase App Indexing](https://docs.branch.io/pages/organic-search/firebase/) feature which seems to be perfect match for us however I am unable to understand following even after going through documentation :

1. Our content(coupons/offers) keeps changing every minute and hence our data is highly dynamic. How can we index all of our data existing + data which keeps getting added in our DB on regular interval.
2. How does whole thing works as in do we need to create Branch Universal object & branch links for all the content there in our db & if yes how can we do it incrementally rather than doing it whole thing again.
3. Do we need to use some API for links/object generation which we can trigger via cron jobs to generate objects & links for all the data there in the DB once daily.
4. If I understood documentation correctly once links/objects are created branch will automatically create internal sitemap & submit it for indexing to google without us to worrying about it right?

Answer (score 0):

1. Unfortunately, you cannot index content directly from your DB. The best way to go about this is to have a reference to the content that you'd like to index on the app and create Branch Universal Objects to automatically index the content. For instance, whenever a user applies the offer/coupon, you will have a reference to the coupon/offer on the app and you can create a Branch Universal Object for the coupon/offer to be indexed.
2. Yes, you will need to create Branch Universal Objects for the Firebase App Indexing to work. One way to do it would be to create Branch Universal Object for every content that you users view. For instance, you can place the code snippet to create Branch Universal Objects on the viewDidLoad() method of offers/coupons page of your app. Thay way, all the offers/coupons viewed by your users will automatically be indexed.
3. No, we do not provide an API for object generation.
4. Yes, once you create Branch Universal Objects on your app, your app will be included in our nightly job to automatically generate sitemaps. These sitemaps can be scraped by Google, and all of the included links can then be indexed. Please note that Branch can only submit the sitemap to be scraped by Google. Once the sitemap is submitted, it is really beyond Branch's control to have Google scrape your content.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications @bharath. However would like to know what is the link that gets mapped to the content which gets indexed (assuming title, description, metadata, image etc) is what gets indexed in google which we set while creating BUO. As in what is the link user gets to see/click on when they see the content is it the deep link which we created using BUO or canonical url that we set while creating BUO.